# how to prove this function is one to one and onto?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let *f(x,y)=2x+y* where a (x, y) point in the grid plane.

Show that *f* is one to one. I have tried to solve it. Please, can you help me solve it?

Comment: ..are you sure? i mean there are multiple (x, y) sets that map to the same f(x, y) value...

Answer (score 1):

For the function to be one-to-one, you would need to show that:

$$f(x,y) = f(a,b) \implies (x,y) = (a,b)$$

But this is false:

$$f(0, 2) = 2 = f(1,0)$$

and clearly

$$(0,2) \not= (1,0)$$

Answer (score 0):

Take the number $4a+b$. This can be expressed as $f(2a,b)$ and also $f(a, 2a+b)$ so this function is not one-to-one.

Comment: my condition y is smaller than or equal to 2

Comment: @haman Such conditions should be included in your initial post. (Although the counterexample I provided *does* satisfy $y \leq 2$...)

Comment: @haman: Take $a,b$ both to be negative then $f(2a,b)=f(a,2a+b)$ and satisfies your new condition $y\leq2$. You should take up Benjamin Dickman's suggestion and edit your post including this condition. As for surjectivity given even number $2k$ we can see that $f(k,0)=2k$, and for an odd number $2k+1$ you can see $f(k,1)=2k+1$.